# How can remove /login in url when using auth Laravel

Tags: laravel, authentication

After i done `php artisan make:auth` then first redirect in browser. Laravel always auto redirect to `blabla.com/login` with login page. How can i remove `/login` in URL of browser and keep content of login page?.
I tried researching in source code, but can't find to customize.

Comment: Does it take you to your home page when you login with the right credentials?

Comment: @ChukwuemekaInya No, i mean that get login page with default APP_URL, no `/login` when first typing in browser

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: @RossWilson Laravel 5.7

Comment: You can write your own routes for authentication and point them to the controllers and their methods. First check all routes to have a reference using php artisan route:list, then remove default Auth::routes() and add your own for each end point specifying what slug you’d like for it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should be able to this by adding the following route underneath `Auth::routes()`:

```
Route::get('/', 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm')->name('login');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this in `web.php`-

```
Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('auth.login');
});
```